# How to clear IE8 browser cache using PHP 5.3

Tags: php, internet-explorer, caching

Hi I need to clear IE8 browser cache before loading my cd-based php application.

My php application is working inside a Dot net application. So before calling my php application I try to call one php page like this.

```
<?php
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Cache: no-cache");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 2001 01:00:00 GMT");
?>
```

But its not clearing IE8 cache properly. How can I clear IE cache using php or jquery?

If any other option available please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot clear the existing items in a browser's cache. You can only specify the cache policy for new items.

Comment: You mean clear the user cache? I don't think it's possible. Moreover, it's an operation where user consent is necessary. You can set (as you did) not to cache a page, but clearing existing history is out of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this code to your php page

```
<?php
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```